# Creating popup windows with content from pgAdminIII in leaflet

Tags: postgresql, leaflet

I am having trouble creating popup windows with content from my postgres database into leaflet.  My database is connected and the points are showing as a layer but popup are not showing content.  How do I specify what attributes to put in window?

Answer (score 2):

When you create your Leaflet layer with geojson features from your database like this:

```
L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

You can use the onEachFeature option to call your own function that will define the popup content for each of your feature:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.YourPropertyName) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.YourPropertyName);
    }
}
```

In this case: The geojson you receive from your database should at least contain the specified property like this:

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "YourPropertyName": "Coors Field",
        "anotherProperty": "Baseball Stadium"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

Hope this help